# Is it possible in C# to restrict method parameter to an class that inherits from another class?

Tags: c#

Can you make a method that requires that a parameter inherits from another?

Say I am writing an external library class.

```
abstract class ImTheBaseClass
{
public int Age {get;set;}
}

class Does : ImTheBaseClass
{}

class AlsoDoes : ImTheBaseClass

class DoesNot
{}
```

Can I write a method that accepts Does and AlsoDoes (Or any number of permutations) as a parameter but rejects DoesNot (at compile time, not run time)?

Comment: your paramater type will be `Does` not the base class

Comment: @AD.Net `DoesNot` doesn't inherit the base class, so using it would be fine as the parameter type.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified...this will be in a library so I don't have control of what they pass in. I'll update my question.

Comment: Simply pass in your parameter as an instance of the base class.

Comment: And also...why the downvote?

Comment: @Webjedi the answer's still the same, your parameter is `ImTheBaseClass`. `DoesNot` doesn't inherit from this, so passing this would never compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes have the parameter as `ImTheBaseClass` type and thus all derived type can be passed in.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that derived type worked that way.

Comment: I knew this was possible with Interfaces but I wasn't looking for varied implementations of methods, I'm really just looking to ensure that a derived class has certain expected properties.

Answer (score 5):

Sure; just declare the parameter as `Does` (or as your base class).

Comment: If you declare the parameter of type `Does` the method won't accept a `AlsoDoes`

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.  You just need to give the base class as the parameter

```
public void MyMethod(ImTheBaseClass myvar)
{
...something
}
```

can then call it like this

```
var x= new Does();
MyMethod(x);
```

Comment: Could also state `Does x = new Does();`, as it's still a subclass of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a base class you could use an interface if it suits your needs then the parameter will be that interface.

```
interface IClass
{
    int Age {get;set;}
}

class Does : IClass
{}

class DoesNot
{}
```

Comment: I don't see how changing the abstract interface to a class make any difference to the question.

Comment: @CharlesMager It doesn't but in my opinion given the example shown an interface makes more sense

Comment: Doesn't really need an interface, but, yes, the principle is the same. He can use the base class or an interface as the parameter's type, if base implementation is not required.

Comment: @CharlesMager, Interface would be better option cause then the consuming method is extensible much more since whichever type implements the interface can be passed in.

Comment: @Rahul I'd say that's a bit of a leap given we have a contrived example and zero context.

Comment: @Rahul that aspect is actually irrelevant to the question though. That's a different question which would be answered by his design requirements. In both cases, the principle is the same: pass in the lower level interface, either base class or actual interface.

Comment: @CharlesMager, Yes that correct but what I said is kind a general principle.